# Deduce return type of member function

Tags: c++, templates, decltype, result-of

In a template function I was trying to create a `std::vector` with its `value_type` being dependent on a member function of the template parameter to the function. This template parameter is restricted to being a vector containing unique pointers of a certain type with a certain function. For example:

```
/* somewhere in the code */
std::vector< std::unique_ptr< Widget > > myVec;
/* work with myVec and fill it, then call the relevant function */
func(myVec);
```

Now the function `func` needs to retrieve the return type of the member function `member_func` of `Widget`. Note that `Widget` can also be a different type, as long as it has the member function `member_func`.

```
template <typename Vec>
void func(const Vec& vec) {
  using ret_type = decltype(Vec::value_type::element_type::member_func()); // Doesn't work
  std::vector< ret_type > local_vec;
}
```

I've tried various things, e.g. `std::result_of`, `std::invoke_result` and `decltype`, but I can't seem to make it work. Is this even possible and if yes, how could it be achieved?

Comment: You can only call the member function on instances of that class, not on the class type (which is what `...::element_type` is). `std::declval`, as used in the answer, is the idiomatic way to get an instance of a type in an unevaluated (e.g. `decltype`) context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this close to what you wanted?

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>

struct Foo
{
    int member_func();
};

template <typename Vec>
void func(const Vec& vec) {

    using ret_type = decltype(std::declval<typename Vec::value_type>()->member_func());

    std::vector< ret_type > local_vec;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> v;
    func(v);
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/g/dJkSf1

Explanation:

`std::declval<typename Vec::value_type>()` generates a reference to a unique_ptr (which must be used in an unevaluated context). We then take the decltype of calling `generated_reference->member_function()`.

This would be the same type as the result of `vec[0]->member_func()`

Indeed, we could write it this way:

```
template <typename Vec>
void func(const Vec& vec) {

    using ret_type = decltype(vec.at(0)->member_func());

    std::vector< ret_type > local_vec;
}
```

Which might be more expressive and generic (`Vec` may now be any type which is vector-like and holds pointer-like things to `Foo`)

Furthermore, the more generically we approach the deduction, the more generic our `func` function becomes:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

struct Foo
{
    int member_func();
};

template <typename Vec>
void func(const Vec& vec) {

    using ret_type = decltype((*std::begin(vec))->member_func());

    std::vector< ret_type > local_vec;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> v;
    func(v);
    func(std::array<std::unique_ptr<Foo>, 10> { });

    Foo* foos[] = { nullptr, nullptr };
    func(foos);

    func(std::set<std::shared_ptr<Foo>, std::owner_less<>> {});
}
```

#### Note

This code assumes that the return_type of `Foo::member_func` is not a reference type.

If that's a possibility, we'd need to decide whether we used metaprogramming to:

a) convert reference types to std::reference_wrapper, so they can be stored in a vector, or

b) convert reference types to fundamental types using `std::decay`, which would result in copies being made.

Comment: it might be useful to `decay_t` `ret_type`, as std::vector doesn't like `const` and reference in type.

Comment: @Jarod42 added note

Comment: Ok, now I get it. I like the more generic approach and settled with `using ret_type = std::decay_t<decltype((*std::begin(vec))->member_func())>;`. Thank you!

Comment: @KorbenDose I agree, I think it's the most expressive. Glad to have helped.